# Is method overloading from different classes possible without inheritance? Many sources claim no. But I don't get any error. Why is that so?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, overloading

Here's an example program

```
class findArea   //Class
{
    public void area(int side) *//method with one int argument*
    {
        System.out.println("The area of square is:"+side*side);
    }
    public void area(int length, int breadth)//method with 2 int arguments
    {
        System.out.println("The area of rectangle is:"+length*breadth);
    }
    public void area(float radius)//method with one float argument
    {
        System.out.println("The area of circle is:"+3.14*radius*radius);
    }
    
}
public class MethodLoad {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        findArea fa = new findArea(); //Object creation
        MethodLoad m =new MethodLoad();//Object creation
        fa.area(4);
        fa.area(7.0f);
        fa.area(5,6);
        m.area(2.0f,3.5f);
    }
    public void area(float base, float height )//method with 2 float arguments
    {
        System.out.println("The area of triangle is:"+0.5*base*height);
    }
    
}
```

Here findArea class and MethodLoad class are not having a parent child relationship. But it is possible to overload method without any error. Someone please clear me whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overloading a method in Java is always within a class, not from different classes

You won't get any error as is allowed what you have done

Answer (score 1):

The `area` method in `MethodLoad` isn't overloading the `area` methods in `findArea`; the `area` methods in `findArea` are overloads of each other, but they're not overloads of the `area` method in `findArea`.

Methods with the same name in unrelated classes aren't overloads: they're just methods with the same name.